# How can I decode Unity's iOS device Token for Push Notifications?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, encoding, push-notification

I'm implementing Unity's [Notification Service](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.NotificationServices.html) for iOS.

I don't believe I have a problem with my implementation.

This is how I'm Registering:

```
NotificationServices.RegisterForNotifications(NotificationType.Badge | 
NotificationType.Alert | NotificationType.Sound, true);
```

I also have Push Notifications enabled in my capabilities.

For getting the device token I use [NotificationServices.deviceToken](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.NotificationServices-deviceToken.html).

The problem with DeviceToken is that it returns a `byte[]` and I don't know how to decode it.
I have tried with several methods, but the only one that gives me something readable is the following:

```
byte[] token = NotificationServices.deviceToken;
Debug.Log(System.BitConverter.ToString(token).Replace("-", ""));
Debug.Log(Convert.ToBase64String(token));
```

- The first method returns me: `348CDFAE308F9107A3DB0807CC363BBB01DEC33008E9F474A9A81D57D039D245`, which, without the replace it would be `34-8C-DF-AE-30-8F-91-07-A3-DB-08-07-CC-36-3B-BB-01-DE-C3-30-08-E9-F4-74-A9-A8-1D-57-D0-39-D2-45`
- The second methods returns me: `cFXd3wLN0aCOpx7vn9pwDlJ24W32m9WO3A+WY28G4Zs=`

**BUT**, and here is the interesting part, if I modify the method that Unity generates when compiling `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken`, with the following example:

```
NSString *token;
token = [deviceToken description];
NSLog(@"Token: %@", token);
```

I get the following result:
`Token: <7055dddf 02cdd1a0 8ea71eef 9fda700e 5956e16d 8e9bd54e dc0f9263 6f03e19b>`

I have tried to send push notifications with all the tokens I have, but none of them work.

So, my question is, *from Unity*, how can I correctly decode the deviceToken for sending push notifications?

Thanks =)

Comment: @Programmer `UTF8: pU���Ѡ�����pRv�m��Վ��co��
Default: pU���Ѡ�����pRv�m��Վ��co��`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that is with the first method:

```
byte[] token = NotificationServices.deviceToken;
return BitConverter.ToString(token).Replace("-", "");
```

Unity gives me everything in capital letters, but it worked while trying push notifications(it looks like iOS doesn't discriminate capital letters). I was making an error by trying to test the development build with a production notification.